# what's the difference between `simp` and `simp!`? Where is `simp!` defined?

Tags: lean

I can't find any information online about the `simp!` tactic, although it is suggested by the autocomplete function on VSCode. I've tried using it and it seems to work differently from `simp`, but while I can trace the definition of `simp` back to its source file, this doesn't seem possible for `simp!`. Is this some syntax I don't know about? Where can I find more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/-- `simp!` is shorthand for `simp` with `autoUnfold := true`.
This will rewrite with all equation lemmas, which can be used to
partially evaluate many definitions. -/
```

https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/2ac782c31593b0abc9ab84f3614895ef14b74e4f/src/Init/Meta.lean#L1340-L1343

Comment: thanks a lot! do you know why VSCode can't figure out that the declaration is in Mean.lean?